# Pandas: Randomize letters in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
id1           | id2
----------------------------
ab51c-ee-1a   | cga--=%abd21
```

I am looking to randomize the letters only:

```
id1           | id2
----------------------------
ge51r-eq-1b   | olp--=%cqw21
```

I think I can do something like this:

```
newid1 = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    string = ''
    for i in row['id1']:
        if i.isalpha():
            string+=random.choice(string.letters)
        else:
            string+=i
    newcolumn.append(string)
```

But it doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets use `apply`, with the power of `str.replace` to replace only alphabets using regex i.e

```
import string 
import random

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

def rand(stri):
    return random.choice(letters)

df.apply(lambda x : x.str.replace('[a-z]',rand))
```

Output :

```
           id1            id2
0  gp51e-id-1v      jvj--=%glw21
```

For one specific column use

```
df['id1'].str.replace('[a-z]',rand)
```

---

Added by [@antonvbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7386332/anton-vbr): For future reference, if we want to change upper and lower case we could do this:

```
letters = dict(u=list(string.ascii_uppercase),l=list(string.ascii_lowercase))

(df['id1'].str.replace('[a-z]',lambda x: random.choice(letters['l']))
          .str.replace('[A-Z]',lambda x: random.choice(letters['u'])))
```

Comment: Glad can help. Do vote when you get enough reputation.

Comment: Will do! One more question - how could I apply this just one column? I tried df['id1'].apply(lambda x : x.str.replace('[a-z]', rand)) but got an error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Thats a lot simpler you can do `df['id1'].str.replace('[a-z]',rand)`

Comment: Nice answer +1, I added the case where we want to change both lower and upper case if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you sir. I appreciate your help. That definitely will help the future users.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase as al
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['ab51c-ee-1a'],
                   'id2': ['cga--=%abd21']})

al = list(al)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: ''.join([random.choice(al) if i in al else i for i in list(x)]))
```

Comment: This worked as well thanks - seemed to take a bit longer than @bharath's one (edit: maybe not - may have just been my internet)

Comment: You are welcome, I added df creation to help others who may have better ideas.

Comment: @Bharath Obviously :)

Comment: Ultra instinct? I loved that episode. Still waiting for him to turn once again. All new episodes are boring.