# regex replace using function python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to print a table of my database using :

```
pd.read_sql_query("SELECT name,duration FROM activity where (strftime('%W', date) = strftime('%W', 'now'))", conn))
```

and it work it prints :

```
                   name  duration
 0        programmation       150
 1              lecture        40
 2                  ctf        90
 3                  ceh        90
 4        deep learning       133
 5  vm capture the flag       100
```

but I would like to use my function minuteToStr who translate the duration to string likes "1h30" on the duraton colowns.
I tried this code but it does'nt work :

```
tableau = str(pd.read_sql_query("SELECT name,duration FROM activity\
                 where (strftime('%W', date) = strftime('%W', 'now'))", conn))  
tableau = re.sub("([0-9]{2,})",   minuteToStr(int("\\1")), tableau)
print(tableau)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub` doesn't work this way. It expects a string, not a DataFrame.

Given that `minuteToStr` accepts an integer, you can simply use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
tableau['duration'] = tableau['duration'].apply(minuteToStr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I'll use this solution .

Answer (score 3):

Make this easy, just use a little mathemagic and string formatting.

```
h = df.duration // 60
m = df.duration % 60

df['duration'] = h.astype(str) + 'h' + m.astype(str) + 'm'
df

                  name duration
0        programmation    2h30m
1              lecture    0h40m
2                  ctf    1h30m
3                  ceh    1h30m
4        deep learning    2h13m
5  vm capture the flag    1h40m
```

Comment: This is certainly the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: @Bharath Passed you an upvote too, and the answer you linked ;-)

Comment: Thank you.My solution might help future users who has duration like 120 mins or so.

Comment: @Neolex Just letting you know that `apply` is much slower.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to using a function inside `re.sub` in pandas  we can use `str.replace` . Similar type is used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078034/pandas-randomize-letters-in-a-column/47078518#47078518) i.e

If duration column is of integer type then

```
tableau['duration'].astype(str).str.replace("([0-9]{2,})", minuteToStr)
```

Else:

```
tableau['duration'].str.replace("([0-9]{2,})", minuteToStr)
```

To illustrate using function inside replace (I prefer you go with @colspeed's solution)

```
def minuteToStr(x):
    h = int(x.group(1)) // 60
    m = int(x.group(1)) % 60
    return str(h) + 'h' + str(m)


df['duration'].astype(str).str.replace("([0-9]{2,})",minuteToStr)
```

```
            name duration
0     programmation     2h30
1           lecture     0h40
2               ctf     1h30
3               ceh     1h30
4      deeplearning     2h13
5  vmcapturetheflag     1h40
```

Comment: Thank's for your help, but it doesnt work ... 
I got :
`                   name  duration
0        programmation       NaN
1              lecture       NaN
2                  ctf       NaN
3                  ceh       NaN
4        deep learning       NaN
5  vm capture the flag       NaN
6        programmation       NaN
`

Comment: Its better you provide the function `minuteToStr` in the question.

Comment: @Neolex check the update this is how you should use function inside replace. Hope it helps.